# Finding out which CSS property is being animated by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see that `$element.is(':animated')` tells me if $element is being animated but is it possible to see which css properties are being animated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, passing a `step` function to the animate() call would allow you to find out what property is being animated via `fx.prop`. Here is an example from the jQuery API docs:

```
$('li').animate({
  opacity: .5,
  height: '50%'
},
{
  step: function(now, fx) {
    var data = fx.elem.id + ' ' + fx.prop + ': ' + now;
    $('body').append('<div>' + data + '</div>');
  }
});
```

The two arguments to the `step` function are as follows:

> **now**: the numeric value of the property being animated at each step
>
> **fx**: a reference to the `jQuery.fx` prototype object, which contains a number
>   of properties such as `elem` for the animated element, `start` and `end` for
>   the first and last value of the animated property, respectively, and
>   `prop` for the property being animated.

Note that this function runs every "step" of the animation, so it will fire quite often. You could use it to update an array of currently-animating properties or similar.